# unexpected token s in json position 19 - loopback.js error

Tags: loopbackjs

i am using loopback.js for my pet project. I am using loopback explorer to post some data. When i post, i get this error

```
   {
  "error": {
    "statusCode": 400,
    "name": "SyntaxError",
    "message": "Unexpected token s in JSON at position 19",
    "expose": true,
    "status": 400,
    "body": "{\n  \"project\": {\n  selectedroom:\"\",\n  setcolor:false,\n  hours:2,\n  searchterm:\"\",\n  user:\"restlessankur@gmail.com\",\n\ndropdownvalue:1,\ndropdownvaluetwo:1,\nchatrooms:[\n           {\n             saved:true,\n             key:1,\n\n             tasktagssuggestions:[\"mango\", \"pineapple\", \"orange\", \"pear\"],\n            color:false,\n            name:\"private-messages\",\n\n            notepad:\"first one\",\n            text:\"ankur\",\n            \"messages\":[{\n                \"type\" : 0,\n                \"image\": \"https://i2.wp.com/charlottelifeandhome.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/Headshot-round.png\",\n                \"text\": \"project 1 , Hello! Good Morning!,how are you ankur\",\n                \"date\":\"Wed Oct 11 2017 11:32:19 GMT+0530 (IST)\"\n            }, {\n                \"type\": 1,\n                \"image\": \"https://static1.squarespace.com/static/53a7236ee4b0370cf58d8c89/5478ceefe4b0542adccf11df/5478ceeee4b0542adccf11c4/1417203462225/Will-headshot-round-small.jpg\",\n                \"text\": \"project 1 ,Hello! Good Afternoon!\",\n                \"date\":\"Wed Oct 11 2017 11:32:19 GMT+0530 (IST)\"\n            }],\n            expandtask:null,\n            membersofproject:[\n                              {text: 'a',value: 'a'},\n                              {text: 'b',value: 'b'},\n                              {text: 'c',value: 'c'},\n                              {text: 'd',value: 'd'},\n                              {text: 's',value: 's'},\n                              {text: 'e',value: 'e'},\n                            ],\n            tasks:[\n              {\n                id:0,\n                taskname:\"private message go to school\",\n                doer:[{key:\"jenny\",text: 'Jenny ank Hess',value: 'Jenny Hess'}],\n                startdate:\"\",\n                taskStatusLive:true,\n                enddate:\"\",\n                description:\"description for project 1\",\n               files:[\"file.docs\",\"doc1.txt\"],\n               priority:\"high\",\n               followers:[{key:\"jenny\",text: 'Jenny ank Hess',value: 'Jenny Hess'}],\n               repeats:\"\",\n               reminders:[],\n               tags:[],\n                tasktags:[{ id: 0, text: \"3Thailand\" }, { id: 1, text: \"3India\" }]\n             },\n             {\n               id:1,\n               taskname:\"web design\",\n               doer:[{text: ' 2 2 2 Jenny ank Hess',value: 'Jenny Hess'}],\n               startdate:\"\",\n               taskStatusLive:true,\n               enddate:\"\",\n               description:\"description for project 1\",\n               files:[\"file.docs\",\"doc1.txt\"],\n               priority:\"low\",\n               followers:[{key:\"jenny\",text: 'Jenny ank Hess',value: 'Jenny Hess'}],\n               repeats:\"\",\n               reminders:[],\n               tags:[],\n                tasktags:[{ id: 0, text: \"Thailand\" }, { id: 1, text: \"India\" }]\n             }\n\n\n\n             ]\n          },\n          {\n            key:2,\n            tasktags:[{ id: 0, text: \"Thailand\" }, { id: 1, text: \"India\" }],\n            tasktagssuggestions:[\"mango\", \"pineapple\", \"orange\", \"pear\"],\n            color:false,\n            name:\"project2\",\n            notepad:\"this is great\",\n            text:\"megha\",\n            \"messages\":[{\n                \"type\" : 0,\n                \"image\": \"https://i2.wp.com/charlottelifeandhome.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/Headshot-round.png\",\n                \"text\": \"project 2, Hello! Good Morning!,how are you ankur\",\n                \"date\":\"Wed Oct 11 2017 11:32:19 GMT+0530 (IST)\"\n            }, {\n                \"type\": 1,\n                \"image\": \"https://static1.squarespace.com/static/53a7236ee4b0370cf58d8c89/5478ceefe4b0542adccf11df/5478ceeee4b0542adccf11c4/1417203462225/Will-headshot-round-small.jpg\",\n                \"text\": \"project 2, Hello! Good Afternoon!\",\n                \"date\":\"Wed Oct 11 2017 11:32:19 GMT+0530 (IST)\"\n            }],\n            expandtask:null,\n            membersofproject:[\n                              {text: 'rajpura',value: 'rajpura'},\n                              {text: 'patiala',value: 'patiala'},\n                              {text: 'sangrur',value: 'sangrur'},\n                              {text: 'bathinda',value: 'bathinda'},\n                              {text: 'delhi',value: 'delhi'},\n                              {text: 'gur',value: 'gur'},\n                            ],\n            tasks:[\n              {\n                id:0,\n                taskname:\"project 2 go to school\",\n                doer:[{text: 'patiala',value: 'patiala'}],\n                startdate:\"\",\n                taskStatusLive:true,\n                enddate:\"\",\n                description:\"description for project 1\",\n               files:[\"file.docs\",\"doc1.txt\"],\n               priority:\"high\",\n               followers:[{key:\"jenny\",text: 'Jenny ank Hess',value: 'Jenny Hess'}],\n               repeats:\"\",\n               reminders:[],\n               tags:[],\n               tasktags:[{ id: 0, text: \"4Thailand\" }, { id: 1, text: \"4India\" }]\n             },\n             {\n               id:1,\n               taskname:\"web design\",\n               doer:[\"ankur\",\"megha\"],\n               startdate:\"\",\n               taskStatusLive:true,\n               enddate:\"\",\n               description:\"description for project 1\",\n               files:[\"file.docs\",\"doc1.txt\"],\n               priority:\"low\",\n               followers:[{key:\"jenny\",text: 'Jenny ank Hess',value: 'Jenny Hess'}],\n               repeats:\"\",\n               reminders:[],\n               tags:[],\n               tasktags:[{ id: 0, text: \"Thailand\" }, { id: 1, text: \"India\" }]\n             }\n\n\n\n        ]\n        },\n          {\n            key:3,\n\n            tasktagssuggestions:[\"mango\", \"pineapple\", \"orange\", \"pear\"],\n            color:false,\n            name:\"project3\",\n            notepad:\"awesome is awesome\",\n            text:\"yeah\",\n            \"messages\":[{\n                \"type\" : 0,\n                \"image\": \"https://i2.wp.com/charlottelifeandhome.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/Headshot-round.png\",\n                \"text\": \"project 3,Hello! Good Morning!,how are you ankur\",\n                \"date\":\"Wed Oct 11 2017 11:32:19 GMT+0530 (IST)\"\n            }, {\n                \"type\": 1,\n                \"image\": \"https://static1.squarespace.com/static/53a7236ee4b0370cf58d8c89/5478ceefe4b0542adccf11df/5478ceeee4b0542adccf11c4/1417203462225/Will-headshot-round-small.jpg\",\n                \"text\": \"project 3, Hello! Good Afternoon!\",\n                \"date\":\"Wed Oct 11 2017 11:32:19 GMT+0530 (IST)\"\n            }],\n            expandtask:null,\n            membersofproject:[\n                              {text: 'pen',value: 'pen'},\n                              {text: 'pencil',value: 'pencil'},\n                              {text: 'lo',value: 'lo'},\n\n                            ],\n            tasks:[\n              {\n                id:0,\n                taskname:\"project 3 go to school\",\n                doer:[{text: 'rajpura',value: 'rajpura'}],\n                startdate:\"\",\n                taskStatusLive:true,\n                enddate:\"\",\n                description:\"description for project 1\",\n               files:[\"file.docs\",\"doc1.txt\"],\n               priority:\"high\",\n               followers:[{key:\"jenny\",text: 'Jenny ank Hess',value: 'Jenny Hess'}],\n               repeats:\"\",\n               reminders:[],\n               tags:[],\n               tasktags:[{ id: 0, text: \"Thailand\" }, { id: 1, text: \"India\" }]\n             },\n             {\n               id:1,\n               taskname:\"web design\",\n               doer:[\"ankur\",\"megha\"],\n               startdate:\"\",\n               taskStatusLive:true,\n               enddate:\"\",\n               description:\"description for project 1\",\n               files:[\"file.docs\",\"doc1.txt\"],\n               priority:\"low\",\n               followers:[{key:\"jenny\",text: 'Jenny ank Hess',value: 'Jenny Hess'}],\n               repeats:\"\",\n               reminders:[],\n               tags:[],\n               tasktags:[{ id: 0, text: \"Thailand\" }, { id: 1, text: \"India\" }]\n             }\n\n\n\n        ]\n          },\n          {\n            key:4,\n\n            tasktagssuggestions:[\"mango\", \"pineapple\", \"orange\", \"pear\"],\n            color:false,\n            name:\"project 4\",\n            notepad:\"hulk hulk\",\n            text:\"shimla\",\n            \"messages\":[{\n                \"type\" : 0,\n                \"image\": \"https://i2.wp.com/charlottelifeandhome.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/Headshot-round.png\",\n                \"text\": \"project 4, Hello! Good Morning!,how are you ankur\",\n                \"date\":\"Wed Oct 11 2017 11:32:19 GMT+0530 (IST)\"\n            }, {\n                \"type\": 1,\n                \"image\": \"https://static1.squarespace.com/static/53a7236ee4b0370cf58d8c89/5478ceefe4b0542adccf11df/5478ceeee4b0542adccf11c4/1417203462225/Will-headshot-round-small.jpg\",\n                \"text\": \"project 4 ,Hello! Good Afternoon!\",\n                \"date\":\"Wed Oct 11 2017 11:32:19 GMT+0530 (IST)\"\n            }],\n            expandtask:null,\n            membersofproject:[\n                              {text: 'laptop',value: 'laptop'},\n                              {text: 'mouse',value: 'mouse'},\n                              {text: 'pc',value: 'pc'},\n\n                            ],\n            tasks:[\n              {\n                id:0,\n                taskname:\"project 4 go to school\",\n                doer:[{text: 'barnala',value: 'barnala'}],\n                startdate:\"\",\n                taskStatusLive:true,\n                enddate:\"\",\n                description:\"description for project 1\",\n               files:[\"file.docs\",\"doc1.txt\"],\n               priority:\"high\",\n               followers:[{key:\"jenny\",text: 'Jenny ank Hess',value: 'Jenny Hess'}],\n               repeats:\"\",\n               reminders:[],\n               tags:[],\n               tasktags:[{ id: 0, text: \"Thailand\" }, { id: 1, text: \"India\" }]\n             },\n             {\n               id:1,\n               taskname:\"web design\",\n               doer:[\"ankur\",\"megha\"],\n               startdate:\"\",\n               taskStatusLive:true,\n               enddate:\"\",\n               description:\"description for project 1\",\n               files:[\"file.docs\",\"doc1.txt\"],\n               priority:\"low\",\n               followers:[{key:\"jenny\",text: 'Jenny ank Hess',value: 'Jenny Hess'}],\n               repeats:\"\",\n               reminders:[],\n               tags:[],\n               tasktags:[{ id: 0, text: \"Thailand\" }, { id: 1, text: \"India\" }]\n             }\n\n\n\n              ]\n         },\n          {\n            key:5,\n\n            tasktagssuggestions:[\"mango\", \"pineapple\", \"orange\", \"pear\"],\n            color:false,\n            name:\"project 5\",\n            notepad:\"going to new york\",\n            text:\"delhi\",\n            \"messages\":[{\n                \"type\" : 0,\n                \"image\": \"https://i2.wp.com/charlottelifeandhome.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/Headshot-round.png\",\n                \"text\": \"project 5 Hello! Good Morning!,how are you ankur\",\n                \"date\":\"Wed Oct 11 2017 11:32:19 GMT+0530 (IST)\"\n            }, {\n                \"type\": 1,\n                \"image\": \"https://static1.squarespace.com/static/53a7236ee4b0370cf58d8c89/5478ceefe4b0542adccf11df/5478ceeee4b0542adccf11c4/1417203462225/Will-headshot-round-small.jpg\",\n                \"text\": \"project 5 Hello! Good Afternoon!\",\n                \"date\":\"Wed Oct 11 2017 11:32:19 GMT+0530 (IST)\"\n            }],\n            expandtask:null,\n            membersofproject:[\n                              {text: 'ko',value: 'ko'},\n                              {text: 'jo',value: 'jo'},\n                              {text: 'co',value: 'co'},\n\n                            ],\n            tasks:[\n              {\n                id:0,\n                taskname:\"project 5 go to school\",\n                doer:[{text: 'almirah',value: 'almirah'}],\n                startdate:\"\",\n                taskStatusLive:true,\n                enddate:\"\",\n                description:\"description for project 1\",\n               files:[\"file.docs\",\"doc1.txt\"],\n               priority:\"high\",\n               followers:[{key:\"jenny\",text: 'Jenny ank Hess',value: 'Jenny Hess'}],\n               repeats:\"\",\n               reminders:[],\n               tags:[],\n               tasktags:[{ id: 0, text: \"Thailand\" }, { id: 1, text: \"India\" }]\n             },\n             {\n               id:1,\n               taskname:\"web design\",\n               doer:[\"ankur\",\"megha\"],\n               startdate:\"\",\n               taskStatusLive:true,\n               enddate:\"\",\n               description:\"description for project 1\",\n               files:[\"file.docs\",\"doc1.txt\"],\n               priority:\"low\",\n               followers:[{key:\"jenny\",text: 'Jenny ank Hess',value: 'Jenny Hess'}],\n               repeats:\"\",\n               reminders:[],\n               tags:[],\n               tasktags:[{ id: 0, text: \"Thailand\" }, { id: 1, text: \"India\" }]\n             }\n\n\n\n        ]\n         },\n          {\n            key:6,\n\n            tasktagssuggestions:[\"mango\", \"pineapple\", \"orange\", \"pear\"],\n            color:false,\n            name:\"project 6\",\n            notepad:\"coming back to london\",\n            text:\"rajpura\",\n            \"messages\":[{\n                \"type\" : 0,\n                \"image\": \"https://i2.wp.com/charlottelifeandhome.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/Headshot-round.png\",\n                \"text\": \"project 6 Hello! Good Morning!,how are you ankur\",\n                \"date\":\"Wed Oct 11 2017 11:32:19 GMT+0530 (IST)\"\n            }, {\n                \"type\": 1,\n                \"image\": \"https://static1.squarespace.com/static/53a7236ee4b0370cf58d8c89/5478ceefe4b0542adccf11df/5478ceeee4b0542adccf11c4/1417203462225/Will-headshot-round-small.jpg\",\n                \"text\": \"project 6 Hello! Good Afternoon!\",\n                \"date\":\"Wed Oct 11 2017 11:32:19 GMT+0530 (IST)\"\n            }],\n            expandtask:null,\n            membersofproject:[\n                              {text: 'fan',value: 'fan'},\n                              {text: 'pan',value: 'pan'},\n                              {text: 'can',value: 'can'},\n\n                            ],\n            tasks:[\n              {\n                id:0,\n                taskname:\"project 7 go to school\",\n                doer:[{text: 'laptop',value: 'laptop'}],\n                startdate:\"\",\n                taskStatusLive:true,\n                enddate:\"\",\n                description:\"description for project 1\",\n               files:[\"file.docs\",\"doc1.txt\"],\n               priority:\"high\",\n               followers:[{key:\"jenny\",text: 'Jenny ank Hess',value: 'Jenny Hess'}],\n               repeats:\"\",\n               reminders:[],\n               tags:[],\n               tasktags:[{ id: 0, text: \"Thailand\" }, { id: 1, text: \"India\" }]\n             },\n             {\n               id:1,\n               taskname:\"web design\",\n               doer:[\"ankur\",\"megha\"],\n               startdate:\"\",\n               taskStatusLive:true,\n               enddate:\"\",\n               description:\"description for project 1\",\n               files:[\"file.docs\",\"doc1.txt\"],\n               priority:\"low\",\n               followers:[{key:\"jenny\",text: 'Jenny ank Hess',value: 'Jenny Hess'}],\n               repeats:\"\",\n               reminders:[],\n               tags:[],\n               tasktags:[{ id: 0, text: \"Thailand\" }, { id: 1, text: \"India\" }]\n             }\n\n\n\n        ]\n          },\n            {\n              key:7,\n\n              tasktagssuggestions:[\"mango\", \"pineapple\", \"orange\", \"pear\"],\n              color:false,\n              name:\"project 7\",\n              notepad:\"the charger is lit\",\n              text:\"paper\",\n              \"messages\":[{\n                  \"type\" : 0,\n                  \"image\": \"https://i2.wp.com/charlottelifeandhome.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/Headshot-round.png\",\n                  \"text\": \"project 7 Hello! Good Morning!,how are you ankur\",\n                  \"date\":\"Wed Oct 11 2017 11:32:19 GMT+0530 (IST)\"\n              }, {\n                  \"type\": 1,\n                  \"image\": \"https://static1.squarespace.com/static/53a7236ee4b0370cf58d8c89/5478ceefe4b0542adccf11df/5478ceeee4b0542adccf11c4/1417203462225/Will-headshot-round-small.jpg\",\n                  \"text\": \"project 7 Hello! Good Afternoon!\",\n                  \"date\":\"Wed Oct 11 2017 11:32:19 GMT+0530 (IST)\"\n              }],\n              expandtask:null,\n              membersofproject:[\n                                {text: 'boy',value: 'boy'},\n                                {text: 'girl',value: 'girl'},\n                                {text: 'parent',value: 'parent'},\n\n                              ],\n              tasks:[\n                {\n                  id:0,\n                  taskname:\"project 7 go to school\",\n                  doer:[{text: 'get u ',value: 'get u'}],\n                  startdate:\"\",\n                  taskStatusLive:true,\n                  enddate:\"\",\n                  description:\"description for project 1\",\n                 files:[\"file.docs\",\"doc1.txt\"],\n                 priority:\"high\",\n                 followers:[{key:\"jenny\",text: 'Jenny ank Hess',value: 'Jenny Hess'}],\n                 repeats:\"\",\n                 reminders:[],\n                 tags:[],\n                 tasktags:[{ id: 0, text: \"Thailand\" }, { id: 1, text: \"India\" }]\n               },\n               {\n                 id:1,\n                 taskname:\"web design\",\n                 doer:[\"ankur\",\"megha\"],\n                 startdate:\"\",\n                 taskStatusLive:true,\n                 enddate:\"\",\n                 description:\"description for project 1\",\n                 files:[\"file.docs\",\"doc1.txt\"],\n                 priority:\"low\",\n                 followers:[{key:\"jenny\",text: 'Jenny ank Hess',value: 'Jenny Hess'}],\n                 repeats:\"\",\n                 reminders:[],\n                 tags:[],\n                 tasktags:[{ id: 0, text: \"Thailand\" }, { id: 1, text: \"India\" }]\n               }\n\n\n\n          ]\n           },\n\n           //start task\n          {\n            key:8,\n\n            tasktagssuggestions:[\"mango\", \"pineapple\", \"orange\", \"pear\"],\n            color:false,\n            name:\"project 8\",\n            notepad:\"running in the ground\",\n            text:\"bharthal\",\n          \"messages\":[{\n              \"type\" : 0,\n              \"image\": \"https://i2.wp.com/charlottelifeandhome.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/Headshot-round.png\",\n              \"text\": \"project 8 Hello! Good Morning!,how are you ankur\",\n              \"date\":\"Wed Oct 11 2017 11:32:19 GMT+0530 (IST)\"\n          }, {\n              \"type\": 1,\n              \"image\": \"https://static1.squarespace.com/static/53a7236ee4b0370cf58d8c89/5478ceefe4b0542adccf11df/5478ceeee4b0542adccf11c4/1417203462225/Will-headshot-round-small.jpg\",\n              \"text\": \"project 8 Hello! Good Afternoon!\",\n              \"date\":\"Wed Oct 11 2017 11:32:19 GMT+0530 (IST)\"\n          }],\n          expandtask:null,\n          membersofproject:[\n                            {text: 'tv',value: 'tv'},\n                            {text: 'bv',value: 'bv'},\n                            {text: 'pv',value: 'pv'},\n\n                          ],\n          tasks:[\n            {\n              id:0,\n              taskname:\"go to school\",\n              doer:[\"ankur\",\"megha\"],\n              startdate:\"\",\n              taskStatusLive:true,\n              enddate:\"\",\n              description:\"description for project 1\",\n             files:[\"file.docs\",\"doc1.txt\"],\n             priority:\"high\",\n             followers:[{key:\"jenny\",text: 'Jenny ank Hess',value: 'Jenny Hess'}],\n             repeats:\"\",\n             reminders:[],\n             tags:[],\n             tasktags:[{ id: 0, text: \"Thailand\" }, { id: 1, text: \"India\" }]\n           },\n           {\n             id:1,\n             taskname:\"web design\",\n             doer:[\"ankur\",\"megha\"],\n             startdate:\"\",\n             taskStatusLive:true,\n             enddate:\"\",\n             description:\"description for project 1\",\n             files:[\"file.docs\",\"doc1.txt\"],\n             priority:\"low\",\n             followers:[{key:\"jenny\",text: 'Jenny ank Hess',value: 'Jenny Hess'}],\n             repeats:\"\",\n             reminders:[],\n             tags:[],\n             tasktags:[{ id: 0, text: \"Thailand\" }, { id: 1, text: \"India\" }]\n           }\n\n\n\n      ]\n         },\n\n         //ends task\n          {\n            key:9,\n\n            tasktagssuggestions:[\"mango\", \"pineapple\", \"orange\", \"pear\"],\n            color:false,\n            name:\"project 9\",\n            notepad:\"abra ka dabra\",\n            text:\"iphone\",\n            \"messages\":[{\n                \"type\" : 0,\n                \"image\": \"https://i2.wp.com/charlottelifeandhome.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/Headshot-round.png\",\n                \"text\": \"project 9 Hello! Good Morning!,how are you ankur\",\n                \"date\":\"Wed Oct 11 2017 11:32:19 GMT+0530 (IST)\"\n            }, {\n                \"type\": 1,\n                \"image\": \"https://static1.squarespace.com/static/53a7236ee4b0370cf58d8c89/5478ceefe4b0542adccf11df/5478ceeee4b0542adccf11c4/1417203462225/Will-headshot-round-small.jpg\",\n                \"text\": \"project 9 Hello! Good Afternoon!\",\n                \"date\":\"Wed Oct 11 2017 11:32:19 GMT+0530 (IST)\"\n            }],\n            expandtask:null,\n            membersofproject:[\n                              {text: 'mkm',value: 'mkm'},\n                              {text: 'bkm',value: 'bkm'},\n                              {text: 'ckm',value: 'ckm'},\n\n                            ],\n            tasks:[\n              {\n                id:0,\n                taskname:\"go to school\",\n                doer:[\"ankur\",\"megha\"],\n                startdate:\"\",\n                taskStatusLive:true,\n                enddate:\"\",\n                description:\"description for project 1\",\n               files:[\"file.docs\",\"doc1.txt\"],\n               priority:\"high\",\n               followers:[{key:\"jenny\",text: 'Jenny ank Hess',value: 'Jenny Hess'}],\n               repeats:\"\",\n               reminders:[],\n               tags:[],\n               tasktags:[{ id: 0, text: \"1Thailand\" }, { id: 1, text: \"1India\" }]\n             },\n             {\n               id:1,\n               taskname:\"web design\",\n               doer:[\"ankur\",\"megha\"],\n               startdate:\"\",\n               taskStatusLive:true,\n               enddate:\"\",\n               description:\"description for project 1\",\n               files:[\"file.docs\",\"doc1.txt\"],\n               priority:\"low\",\n               followers:[{key:\"jenny\",text: 'Jenny ank Hess',value: 'Jenny Hess'}],\n               repeats:\"\",\n               reminders:[],\n               tags:[],\n               tasktags:[{ id: 0, text: \"2Thailand\" }, { id: 1, text: \"2India\" }]\n             }\n\n\n\n        ]\n        }\n      ]}}",
    "type": "entity.parse.failed",
    "stack": "SyntaxError: Unexpected token s in JSON at position 19\n    at Object.parse (native)\n    at parse (/Users/ankursharma/Documents/projects/meetupz/node_modules/body-parser/lib/types/json.js:89:19)\n    at /Users/ankursharma/Documents/projects/meetupz/node_modules/body-parser/lib/read.js:121:18\n    at invokeCallback (/Users/ankursharma/Documents/projects/meetupz/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:224:16)\n    at done (/Users/ankursharma/Documents/projects/meetupz/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:213:7)\n    at IncomingMessage.onEnd (/Users/ankursharma/Documents/projects/meetupz/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:273:7)\n    at emitNone (events.js:86:13)\n    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:185:7)\n    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:974:12)\n    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:80:11)\n    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:104:9)"
  }
}
```

what does this error means? I have an object. It contains lot of stuff.  Thats why when i selected the model, i choose "any" . I am experimenting. But, this isnt working.

Comment: That JSON body doesn't seem valid.

Comment: yes thanks. You should have posted this an answer. I should have accepted it.